# Having issue rendering components with radio buttons multiple times

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, radio-group

A bit of context first, I'm working a questionnaire and decided to start learning React.js. Each step of the questionnaire includes a question and a yes/no radio button group, and also navigation buttons. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/8361/). The question component is pretty straight forward, I'm passing the formData and save data function to it in the parent component.

And code for the question component

```
var Question = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
        }
    },
    createMarkup: function(html) {
        return {
            __html: html
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        var subtitle = this.props.subtitle || '';
        var name = this.props.name;
        if (this.props.formData[name] === undefined) {
            var answer_yes = null;
            var answer_no = null;
        } else {
            answer_yes = this.props.formData[name] == "yes" ? true : null;
            answer_no = this.props.formData[name] == "no" ? true : null;
        }
        console.log(answer_yes);
        console.log(answer_no);
        return (
            <div className="container-question">
                <label className="default" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(this.props.question)}></label>
                <span className="alert subtitle" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(subtitle)}></span>
                <div className="form-group form-group-radio">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-4">
                            <input type="radio" id={name + "_yes"} name={name} value="yes" defaultChecked={answer_yes} onChange={this.props.saveData}/><label htmlFor="yes">Yes</label><br></br>
                            <input type="radio" id={name + "_no"} name={name} value="no" defaultChecked={answer_no} onChange={this.props.saveData}/><label htmlFor="no">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

The problem is that when you select your answer on the first question and click on next, the radio control on the second question change with it, and same thing happens when you answer second question first. I'm storing the boolean variable for defaultChecked as local variables in the render function and logging them in the console.

Is there any obvious mistake i'm making? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an updated jsfiddle that works: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/8365/

The issue is that you're using what is a called an 'uncontrolled component' in React. See this page for more details: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Changing to a controlled component for your scenario means using `checked` instead of `defaultChecked`. `defaultChecked` is meant for uncontrolled components where the values of the input controls (in your case radio buttons) are not controlled by the component's `props` or `render` method. React is really designed to use controlled components where `props`/`state`/`render` drive exactly what the UI shows.

The first thing you'll notice when changing from using `defaultChecked` to `checked` is that you will no longer be able to change the radio state in the UI. The reason this happens is because although the state of your application is being changed in your `saveData` function, your component is not being re-rendered.

There are a few different approaches to handling this. The updated jsfiddle is re-rendering your application during `saveData`. Ideally this should be factored differently. Either the `saveData` should be moved out of the parent component and into a `FormDataStore` concept (see React Flux architecture,  https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) or the parent component should own the `formData` state and call `setState` on itself in `saveData` which will then cause a re-render of that portion of the DOM tree.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I've opted to have the parent component own the formData state. Thank you for the explanation.